# comparing two text files using matlab code

Tags: matlab

How can i compare two text files (file_A has 7 columns and 16k rows and file_B has 6 columns and 7k rows) and match the 1st column of these files and get all the matched rows from file_A?

Here is part of my files and my code. The code is not working. How can I correct it?

```
                           (file_B.txt)

  node     s1           s2           s3          sint         seq
   1      5.9931      -6.9970      -47.741       53.734       48.560     
   2      8.2001      -5.4770      -40.879       49.079       43.870     
   5      6.9113      -4.2943      -32.534       39.445       35.206     
   9      4.4132      -3.7089      -26.543       30.956       27.799 


                          (file_A.txt)      

  node    x      y      z  thxy  thyz thzx
   1    304.17  7.57    0    0    0    0
   2    311.5   7.57    0    0    0    0
   3    309.63  7.57    0    0    0    0
   4    316.96  7.57    0    0    0    0
   5    318.83  7.57    0    0    0    0
   6    331.62  7.57    0    0    0    0
   7    333.49  7.57    0    0    0    0
   8    324.29  7.57    0    0    0    0
   9    326.16  7.57    0    0    0    0
```

And I want matched rows from (file_A.txt) just like this:

```
  node    x      y      z  thxy  thyz thzx
   1    304.17  7.57    0    0    0    0
   2    311.5   7.57    0    0    0    0
   5    318.83  7.57    0    0    0    0
   9    326.16  7.57    0    0    0    0
```

Matlab code:

```
id = fopen('file_A.txt','r'); 
A = cell2mat(textscan(id,'%d %d','headerlines',1));
fclose(id);
id = fopen('file_B.txt','r'); 
B = cell2mat(textscan(id,'%d %d %d','headerlines',1));
fclose(id);

solution = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)(B(find(A(i,1) == B(:,1),1,'first'),:)),1:size(A,1),'uni',0)');
```

Comment: Could you add some sample content of the two text files? So it is clear what they look like, and what you actually want to compare. Also add what you expected output looks like.

Comment: Sounds like the 2nd output of `ismember` would give you everything you need. Without a [mcve] it's impossible to give any more detailed advice.

Comment: @rinkert now it's clear i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reading of the files is not going right. First, by using `'%d'` you are reading all the numbers as integers, and you thus loose precision (all numbers are rounded to the closest integer).

Second, the number of columns you specify does not correspond to the number of columns in either file, and thus `textscan` will not put the data in the required columns, but rather make a long vector, or other shaped matrix/cell array.

To let Matlab read the data as floating point data (i.e. doubles in Matlab), you can use the `'%f'` (see doc of [`textscan`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btghhyz-1-formatSpec))

```
id = fopen('file_A.txt','r'); 
A = cell2mat(textscan(id,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f','headerlines',1));
fclose(id);


id = fopen('file_B.txt','r'); 
B = cell2mat(textscan(id,'%f %f %f %f %f %f','headerlines',1));
fclose(id);
```

Lastly, your way of finding the required rows does work, but a bit easier to read solution is the [`ismember`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function. This checks whether the values in B are in A (only the first column, as this is your selection criterion). This returns a logical array, that has a one at all the indices where membership is found. Use this logical array to select the right rows from A.

```
% solution, check if members of B are in A.
solution = A(ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)),:)
```